# Using different buttons to get to the same ViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, button, viewcontroller

I am creating a game on XCode that has a menu with buttons for setup conditions (i.e., "Play to 30", "Play to 20", etc.). I want these buttons to create a segue to the same `ViewController` that has my game, with the only difference being how many points must be achieved until the game is over. It is far too inefficient to have multiples of the same `ViewController` for each setting. Is there a way around this?

Comment: If you segue to a new view controller, an instance is created—if you go back, this view controller is deallocated.

Answer (score 0):

In your game  view controller create a custom initializer in as so:

```
// add in GameViewController.m
@implementation GameViewController
-(id)initWithLimit:(int)limit {
    self = [super initWithNibName:@"NibName" bundle:nil];
    if (self) {
       _limit = limit;
    }
    return self;
}

// add in GameViewController.h
@interface GameViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic) int limit;
@end
```

implement the menu's button actions as so:

```
-(IBAction)play30 {
     GameViewController *game = [[GameViewController alloc] initWithLimit:30];

     // Handle game view here.
}
```

this answer assumes you create a new instance of GameViewController when the user taps the button. 
if you don't want to instantiate a new ViewControllerSubclass each time the button is taped  then you can create a GameViewController property in you menu view controller and use lazy instantiation for the game view controller:

```
 - (GameViewController *)game {
      if (!_game) _game = ...;
      return _game;
 }

 -(IBAction)play20 {
     // Assuming game is a property.
     self.game.limit = 20;

     // Perform setup that expects the limit property to be set.
     [self.game setup];

     // Handle game view here.
}
```

Hope this helped :)

Comment: Is there a way to do this without nib files?  When I created my project I decided to deselect that option. @Benjamin

Comment: yes, simply add the custom initializer to the game view controller but use, self = [super init]; instead the rest is the same, if you want I can post another answer that explains the more in depth.